# Need to stop words in txt file overwriting JAVA

Tags: java, file, text, joptionpane

Hi im trying to create a word list using a .txt file where i take input off the user from a JOptionPane window and it stores it on a new line of the text file. the problem I'm having is that when I input more than one word it overwrites the data that is already there. I want it to skip a line and add it onto the current list. This is the code I have:

```
public static void Option1Method() throws IOException
{
     FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("wordlist.txt");
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
     String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter word or phrase: ");

     out.println(word);

     out.close();
     aFileWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just put true at the end of the filewriter makes it switch to append mode:

```
public static void Option1Method(){
   FileWriter aFileWriter = null;
   PrintWriter out = null;
      try {
         aFileWriter = new FileWriter("wordlist.txt",true);
         out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
         String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter word or phrase: ");
         out.println(word);
      } catch (IOException iOException) {
      } catch (HeadlessException headlessException) {
      } finally {
         out.close();
         try {
            aFileWriter.close();
         } catch (IOException iOException) {
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are closing the stream at the end of the method.  Each time you call it, it is going to recreate the FileWriter and the PrintWriter, take the input, add it to the file, and then close it again.  One way around this might be to create a static String object, and add the user input to it each time.  At the end of the program, write that string to the file and then close it.